# Need Help to "setup" a RESTful webservice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, installation

I open this topic because I'm going to need a little help for rails and Webservices and also because i am a beginner.

I have now need to "build" a webservice that will enable a third party application (mobile application) to connect to a mySQL database server hosted on my ubuntu 10.04 server

So I have already committed some research and asked some questions and it seems that Rails 3.0 can help me materialize my project by creating a RESTful webservice type (that I don't know yet exactly what it is). Anyway, what I have understood is that I could make requests of kind 'http' in my DB via webservice that will return an XML I can parse.

So I have installed on my server ruby 1.8.7 and gem 1.8.21

I have then launched the famous gem install rails and everything seems ok ... I have Rails in its 3.2.3 version

Only now I 've no idea how to "create" my webservice (and where I must put it ? In /var/www/ to be reach from the web ?) Or how to parameter the 'linker' with a mySQL DB.

I have understood by reading different things on internet setting up a RESTful webservice with rails is not to complicate but i really don't find how to setup mine ... that's why i need help ! A lot of tutorials i've seen are too old. And I really would like advices to set it up !

So you have some tips, some ideas, or tips for m 'refer and help me to put all this in place.

Thanks for all !

Answer (score 1):

A fantastic, up-to-date tutorial that is the very first thing you should look at (in my opinion) is the [Rails Tutorial E-Book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) which you can go over for **free** here.  You're way in over your head right now.